# PersonController issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Following is the code of my person controller

demoApp.controller('PersonCntrl', function ($scope, $route, $location, Person) {

```
$scope.newPerson = {};
$scope.createdPersons = Person.getAll();
***$scope.defaultPerson = $scope.createdPersons[0];***
alert($scope.defaultPerson.Name);
```

Person service return a collection of person objects, which I have bind to my UI and it displays records there.But my $scope.defaultPerson  assignment doesn't have proper object.

```
Following is my controller code:

Person.getAll().then(function (data) {
    $scope.createdPersons = data;
    alert($scope.createdPersons[0].Name);
});
```

Following is my service code:

```
demoApp.factory('Person', function ($resource) {
var resource = $resource('/api/persons/:Id', { Id: '@Id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' }      });
return {
    getAll: function () {           
        return resource.query();
    }};
```

Comment: Can you show your service for `getAll()`?

Comment: Please look at my service code below.

Comment: Now getting the error that Object [object Array] has no method 'then'